# Exec do PHP Voltando caracteres desconhecidos ao executar comandos

Tags: php, windows, cmd

Estou executando funções no CMD do Windows através do PHP na função Exec, porém alguns valores retornados vem como caractere desconhecido, principalmente em acentos, como proceder para corrigir? 
Comando:

```
exec('dir "C:\Users" /b', $x);
```

Resultado:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na saída está me retornando um Array mas tanto dando um var_dump ou print_f os valores ficam como na imagem.

Comment: Utilize o `utf8_encode($text)`

Comment: Continua do mesmo jeito

Comment: Utilize desta forma `<?php header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>` Se estiver utilizando ISO, basta trocar o `UTF-8` por `ISO-8859-1`. Troque os retornos e envios para o banco para `UTF-8` ou `ISO-8859-1` também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/435714/exec-do-php-voltando-caracteres-desconhecidos-ao-executar-comandos#comment842665_435714) e a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435741/3635) estão equivocados, não tem nem sentido forçar codificar neste caso, você pode até optar por usar iso-8859-1 ou utf-8 na resposta HTTP da sua página, mas simplesmente o que o `exec()` retorna não é UTF-8 ou windows-1252 (ou equivalente) em sua codificação, ele provavelmente retorna algum formato do "OEM code page" e em PHP para servidores Windows especificamente já existem funções para tratar isto desde o **PHP 7**, são elas:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sapi-windows-cp-set.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sapi-windows-cp-get.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sapi-windows-cp-conv.php

Basicamente você vai usar isto para pegar o numero que representa o codepage oem:

```
$oem = sapi_windows_cp_get('oem');
```

E vai usar assim para converter no codepage desejado, o equivalente em Windows para o UTF8 é o codepage 65001

```
$var = sapi_windows_cp_conv($oem, 65001, $var);
```

No seu código pode ficar algo como:

```
<?php
exec('dir "C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\aaa" /b', $output);

$codepage = sapi_windows_cp_get('oem');

foreach ($output as $file) {
    $file = sapi_windows_cp_conv($codepage, 65001, $file);

    echo $file, "<br>";
}
```

Vale lembrar que DEPOIS de usar `sapi_windows_cp_conv` e como escolhemos 65001, deve-se setar o charset para UTF-8, pode fazer isso via Apache, Ngnix, ou outro server que esteja usando, ou direto no PHP com `header` no topo:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Mas se em suas páginas precisa/deseja usar iso-8859-1 precisa então, DEPOIS de usar o `sapi_windows_cp_conv`, usar o `utf8_decode` (para DECODIFICAR de UTF8) e também setar o header para iso-8859-1

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

exec('dir "C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\aaa" /b', $output);

$codepage = sapi_windows_cp_get('oem');

foreach ($output as $file) {
    $file = sapi_windows_cp_conv($codepage, 65001, $file);
    $file = utf8_decode($file);

    echo $file, "<br>";
}
```

### Não use exec se não precisar

Agora devo ser sincero, não faço a mínima ideia do porque você resolveu usar o comando `dir "C:\Users" /b` com `exec()`, as vantagens são:

- Não vai precisar ficar ajustando codepage
- Vai rodar no php5 (depende do resto dos seus códigos)
- Vai ser compatível com todos sistemas aonde o PHP é suportado (Windows e Linux por exemplo)

Tem diversas funções para isso, como [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), [`opendir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir) (razoavelmente mais rápida e dá para fornecer um bom controle do manipulador podendo criar uma páginação que não consumiria quase memória alguma diferente das que usam array, mas só se for uma pasta com milhares de arquivos notará alguma melhoria) e [`scandir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), esta ultima é simples e fácil de você aplicar, ficando assim:

```
$dir = 'C:/Users';

foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
    //Ignora as pastas . e .. que são navegações
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        echo $file, "<br>";
    }
}
```

E como bem lembrado pelo colega [@Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco), isso tudo partindo do pressuposto que os arquivos estejam corretos para o *filesystem* em questão.

Comment: Deu certo sua solução, muito obrigado, mas o motivo de eu usar diretamente pelo exec foi por conta de que como vem do cmd, ele não vai mostrar pastas e arquivos especificas, como por exemplo swapfile.sys, System Volume Information, $Recycle.Bin e etc, já que o intuito da aplicação que estou desenvolvendo, deve navegar por qualquer parte do Windows como o Explorer, é certo que os comandos próprios do PHP são bem mais rápidos, mas deixam a desejar em alguns pontos usando o Windows, e pode ficar cansativo encher de exceções no código.

Comment: @JoãoVictor entendi, realmente algumas coisas de Windows são tão especificas que é complicado passar para PHP ou até outras linguagens, pois dependeriam do `windows32 API` e como em outros sistemas arquivos ocultos não funcionam da mesma forma que em windows então tem que ser algo especifico, talvez até com a classe `COM` do PHP conseguiria, mas a complicação seria tanta que realmente neste caso é melhor mesmo `exec`

Answer (score -2):

usa o utf8_string_array_encode($array) com o teu array.

```
function utf8_string_array_encode(&$array){
    $func = function(&$value,&$key){
        if(is_string($value)){
            $value = utf8_encode($value);
        }
        if(is_string($key)){
            $key = utf8_encode($key);
        }
        if(is_array($value)){
            utf8_string_array_encode($value);
        }
    };
    array_walk($array,$func);
    return $array;
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: Mudou, mas agora invés do "ã" aparece "Æ"